# Line-by-line processing of pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

Could you please help to solve a specific task. I need to process pandas DataFrame column line-by-line. The main point is that "None" values must be turned into "0" or "1" so as to proceed "0" or "1" values which are already in the column. I've done it by using a "for" loop, and it works correct:

```
for i in np.arange(1, len(pd['signal'])):
    if df.isnull(df['signal'].iloc[i]) and df['signal'].iloc[i-1] == 0:
        df['signal'].iloc[i] = 0
    if df.isnull(df['signal'].iloc[i]) and df['signal'].iloc[i-1] == 1:
        df['signal'].iloc[i] = 1
```

But, there is the fact that it's not a good approach to iterate the DataFrame.
I tried to use "loc" method, but it brings incorrect results because in this way each step does not consider previously performed results, therefore some "None" values remain unchanged.

```
df.loc[(df.isnull(df['signal'])) & (df['signal'].shift(1) == 0), 'signal'] = 0 
df.loc[(df.isnull(df['signal'])) & (df['signal'].shift(1) == 1), 'signal'] = 1
```

Does anyone have any idea how to implement this task without a "for" loop?

Comment: A quick comment, `pd` is usually the short-hand for `Pandas`, i.e. `import pandas as pd`, avoid using it as your variable.

Comment: And what you are looking for is `ffill`: `df['signal'] = df['signal'].ffill()`.

Comment: Thank you, @Quang Hoang! This is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are vectorized functions for just this purpose that will be *much* faster:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[1,1,np.nan, np.nan], b=[0,1,0,np.nan]))
df.ffill()


# df
     a    b
0  1.0  0.0
1  1.0  1.0
2  NaN  0.0
3  NaN  NaN

# output
     a    b
0  1.0  0.0
1  1.0  1.0
2  1.0  0.0
3  1.0  0.0
```

Comment: Thank you, @anon01! This is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy where:

```
import numpy as np

df['signal'] = np.where(pd.isnull(df['signal']), df['signal'].shift(1), df['signal'])
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment, @Damião Martins, but 'np.where' gives the same incorrect result as 'loc' method does as I described above. 'ffill()' has solved the problem.